# nginx unable to listen to port 80

Tags: nginx, port

I have a web app running on port 8081. I want to use nginx to redirect incoming http traffic to this port. So I have this configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.thing.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

When I try to open the address, I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

However, if I change the port to, say, 81 and connect there, **everything goes smoothly**. I don't understand why. There is nothing running on the machine, only nginx and Artifactory. Firewall is turned off for the time being.

Is there a problem with interacting on port 80? What can cause this?

---

EDIT

I have been using this nginx a few days ago to redirect from 80 to 443 and then from 443 to 8081. (http -> https -> 8081). For debugging purposes now I want to ignore https.

However, for some reason, the port 80 seems to be still redirected to 443, despite no such config being there for nginx.

...

Turns out there must have been a cached redirect in Chrome (originally when the web was visited on port 80 I returned a 301 redirect to port 443. This must've been saved, because when I open an incognito window, it works as expected.

Comment: What's your OS? What user does the nginx master run as? What about the nginx workers?

Comment: CentOS7, all done as root. nginx workers set to auto. netstat shows that there is a nginx process bound to port 80. I just found a weird behavior, will update my question

Comment: yes, that chrome redirect thing is odd. Clients should not be aware of what happens "inside" nginx (e.g. when you use `proxy_pass`), but they will be aware (and will likely cache) explicit redirects.